# Questions regarding mongodb sub-document and spring-data-mongo querying

Tags: mongodb, mapping, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm still trying to get my hands around `mongodb` and how best Entities can be mapped. if you take for example: the entity user and the entity addresses. there could be `one-to-many` when someone is coming from `jpa` background. Here in mongo i don't want to use `dbref`. So addresses are in a `Set` collection in user.

Supposing i was using `spring-data-mongo`:

**Question 1** : should both User and Address have the `@Document` annotation?Or just User?

**Question 2** : what is the best way to query for addresses of a user. It is possible at first place? Because right now I query to get the `User` by `username` or `Id` and then get the addresses of the user.Can I query directly for `sub-document`? if yes how is it done using `spring-data-mongo` Criteria Query:

```
@Document
public class User{
    @Id
    private Long ID;
    private String username;
    private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<Address>();
    ...
} 

@Document
public class Address {
   @Id
   private Long ID;
   private String city;
   private String line1;
   ...

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question 1: No, `@Document` is not strictly necessary at all. We just leverage this on application startup if you activate classpath-scanning for document classes. If you don't the persistence metadata scanning will be done on the first persistence operation. We traverse properties of domain objects then, so `Address` will be discovered.

Question 2: You'll have to read the `User` objects entirely as MongoDB currently does not allow returning sub-documents. So you'll have to query for the entire `User`document but can restrict the fields being returned to the `addresses` field using a `fieldSpec` on the `Query` object or the repository abstraction's `@Query` annotation (see [ref docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/Query.html#fields%28%29)).